# Can Watchify pick up changes to html files?

Tags: javascript, html, browserify, watchify

I import html template files into my javascript components using [babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-html-import-to-string).

When I use watchify, it doesn't update if an html has been changed. Only Javascript file changes. The npm script goes something like this:

`watchify -p browserify-hmr -t [babelify ext .js .html] src/index.js -o public/bundle.js`

Since this doesn't work I am using watch instead, as shown below, but my builds are at least 5 seconds slower than before, when they were instant.

`watch 'npm run browserify' src/ -d --interval=1`
where the browserify script is
`browserify -t [babelify ext .js] src/index.js -o public/bundle.js`

Anyone know how I can run browserify on html file changes without sacrificing fast rebuilds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that browserify never sees the references to the `.html` files, as babelify is replacing them with variables and HTML strings.

If you want watchify to watch the `.html` files and to rebuild the bundle if they change, you should allow babelify to transpile statements like `import some from './some.html'` to `var some = require('./some.html')` and should use a browserify-based transform (like [stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringify)) to transform the required content:

```
watchify \
  -p browserify-hmr \
  -t [babelify ext .js] \
  -t [stringify ext .html] \
  src/index.js -o public/bundle.js
```

Browserify/watchify will then see the `.html` files as being included in the bundle and will watch them for changes.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Here's the slightly reduced syntax I used `watchify -p browserify-hmr -t [babelify ext .js] -t [stringify ext .html] src/index.js -o public/bundle.js`

Comment: @MauroPerez God this was driving me nuts.